# If a series conditionally converges, than the limit of positive terms series and negative term series are equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\Sigma a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series $\Sigma a_n$. If $p_n$ and $q_n$ are the positive part and negative part of $a_n$, respectively, why can I say that $\lim p_n =\lim q_n=0$?

Comment: Because both $|p_n|,|q_n|\le  |a_n|.$

Comment: If a series converge then $a_n\to 0$. A fortiori $p_n,q_n$ are subsequences of $a_n$ so they converge also to $0$.The conditional convergence is not really involved here.

Comment: @zwim   $p_n,q_n$ are usually not subsequences of $a_n.$